# Xamarin.Forms can't see custom entity values on Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this simple piece of code in Xamarin Forms, I can't view the values of  the elements in the list I just declared.

[image]

[image]

Note: this only happens in Android, in iOS I can view the values of the elements in my list.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Visual Studio? Please add a tag for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all `bin` / `obj` folders from solution should solves the issue.

Comment: This worked ! Thank you so much